# Recovery fields from a form in a array

Tags: android, forms, onclick

In my current Android project, I am adding a layout file for an activity composed by a list of EditText fields and a Button in the end.

I am looking for a way to, when the button is clicked, the method associated to the click retrieve all ths fields and store them in a array of Objects (something like `Object object[]`).

Anyone knows if this is possible and how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get a reference to each of the EditTexts and then get their current value, one by one.